# Problem animating size change in a custom-drawn view

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a custom `UIView` that implements `drawRect` to render itself with a gradient background and a 1-pixel black border around the edge, and some text.

In my parent view controller, I am attempting to animate my custom view from its original small size to full-screen, using this code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect detailRect = CGRectOffset(screenRect, 0, -screenRect.origin.y); 
[dayDetail.view setFrame:detailRect];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This works, but `drawRect` in my custom view is only called once when the view is initially created.  As a result the resizing just takes the original small image and blows it up to full screen, so the border of the full-size view is now many pixels wide instead of one, and the text gets expanded in size as well.

Is there any way to set this up so that `drawRect` is called continuously as the view is being animated from small to full-screen?  Basically, I want my custom rendering code to handle the appearance of the view no matter what size it is at any point in time.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the exact same problem and this is how I solved it:

```
dayDetail.view.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
```

That will stretch the middle pixel only. Read the documentation to learn how to modify that behavior. You could certainly ask me, but reading the documentation is probably quicker. Besides, I would probably just quote the documentation.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a try.